# Disable Fast user switching in vista and 7 without admin rights?

Tags: c++, api, registry, admin

i'm writing a security program for vista and 7 (Right now my main os i'm using is 08 server which i'm testing it on as well) and I would like to block the fast user switching option from within windows. The problems is that I can't edit the registry under a normal user as its under the HKLM and I need to be able to edit the key to block it or find another way to accomplish this.

I tried running it as admin and that hasn't worked. With wxDev C++ I tried the manifest option and I still can't get it to work. If the program runs under an admin account though it does.

Would anyway happen to know how to do this? I've been looking on Google all day today now and all I keep finding out is how to edit the reg or group policy to turn it off but I need a way to do it though c++.

Again thank you

Comment: Do you use 64 bit OS?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, are you asking 1) How to write a manifest that makes your program require administrator privileges, or, 2) how to add a manifest to your project in wxDev, or 3) what registry key to set to disable fast user switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry key that controls fast user switching is in key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

it is a DWORD value named `AllowMultipleTSSessions`.

Set it to 0 to disable fast user switching. Windows uses terminal services to implement multiple desktops.

To write to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive, the process must be running with administrator privileges.

The manifest needed to make your process automatically prompt for administrator privileges is:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>`

Comment: Yes that was the problem and thank you for your help. I've been a way for a while so I wasn't able to reply back.